# PHP counterpart of C# WSDL service query using SOAP

Tags: c#, php, soap, wsdl

There is a WSDL service which you can query using the C# as shown below:

```
        arameter p1 = new Parameter();
        p1.Name = "$name";
        p1.Value = "thename";

        Parameter p2 = new Parameter();
        p2.Name = "$surname";
        p2.Value = "thesurname";

        Parameter p3 = new Parameter();
        p3.Name = "$birthyear";
        p3.Value = "1990";

        Parameter p4 = new Parameter();
        p4.Name = "$queryno";
        p4.Value = "999999";

        Query query = new Query();
        query.Name = "TheQueryName";
        query.Parameters = new Parameter[] { p1, p2, p3, p4 };

        ServiceReference1.BASEXSoapClient cli = new BASEXSoapClient();
        cli.Open();
        string s = cli.Execute(query);
        cli.Close();
```

I am trying to create a php counterpart of this code but I am having problems with the query name which does not exist:

```
<?php
 try
{
$client = new  SoapClient( "http://xxxx/BASEX.asmx?WSDL" );

  $request = array('$name'=>'thename',
                     '$surname'=>'thesurname',
                     '$birthyear'=>'1990',
                     '$queryno'=>'999999');

  $response = $client->TheQueryName($request);    

print_r($response);
}
catch (SoapFault $e)
{
    echo "<pre>";
   print_r($e); exit;
echo "<pre>";

}

?>
```

And this is the web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <Execute xmlns="xxxxx/basex">
      <query>
        <Name>string</Name>
        <Parameters>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>string</Name>
            <Value>string</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>string</Name>
            <Value>string</Value>
          </Parameter>
        </Parameters>
      </query>
    </Execute>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <ExecuteResponse xmlns="xxxxx/basex">
      <ExecuteResult>string</ExecuteResult>
    </ExecuteResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

I am told that I can use SOAP instead of BASEX client, as the basex was not working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need the structure below for the parameters. Also your method is `Execute` and it takes the actual name in the `query['Name']` parameter:

```
$request = array(
    'query' => array(
        'Name' => 'TheQueryName',
        'Parameters' => array(
            array('Name' => '$name', 'Value' => 'thename'),
            array('Name' => '$surname', 'Value' => 'thesurname'),
            array('Name' => '$queryno', 'Value' => '999999')
        )
    )
);

$response = $client->Execute($request);
```